# Multiprocessing List Comprehension/Filter

Tags: python, multithreading, list, multiprocessing

I'm trying to multiprocesses a list-comprehension:

```
l = [i for i in range(10) if fun(i)]
```

If I was keeping all the values in the list, I could simply call `pool.map`, but this loop might not keep all values.

How can I go about implementing this?

Comment: Try using a `queue.Queue`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, didn't know about queue; that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Use itertools.compress to filter the results of pool.map.

Here is the serial implementation using filter:

```
ages = [5, 12, 17, 18, 24, 32]

def fun(x):
  if x < 18:
    return False
  else:
    return True

adults = list(filter(fun, ages))

adults
  
Out[29]: [18, 24, 32]
```

The parallel implementation uses map and compress:

```
from itertools import compress
import multiprocessing
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    adult_ages = list(compress(ages, pool.map(fun, ages)))
adult_ages

Out[27]: [18, 24, 32]
```