# How to use parallel processing filter in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I know that in Python, map is equivalent to parallel processing class of `pool.map` from multiprocessing module.
Is there a `filter` equivalent in parallel programming for Python?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-parallel-collections/ look at the link

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [Multiprocessing List Comprehension/Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49620158/12865125)

Answer (score 4):

Python has most of *function orientated programming* paradigms that are necessary. Such as `map`, `filter` and `reduce` [which you can find here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html)

That being said, multiprocessing doesn't support `filter` because lambdas are not pickleable by default.
But you can always implement your own using functions mentioned above or reproducing them in manner that suits you using iterators, generators or list comprehension.

One of examples taken from sagemath is:

```
def pool_filter(pool, func, candidates):
    return [c for c, keep in zip(candidates, pool.map(func, candidates)) if keep]
```

But it further depends on your implementation.

Comment: There is a typo in your example. `p` shall be `pool`